# How do you shrink a larger array into a smaller array?

Tags: c++

I have an array, let's say 200 members, and then a smaller array, let's say 100 members. And if the larger array has 113 members, you can't fit the whole thing into the smaller array. So I want to have it so that it starts from the bottom up and tries to fit as much as it can into the smaller array. How do I do this?

```
int uniq() { static int current = 0; return ++current; }

int main()
{
    int larger_array[200];
    int smaller_array[100];
    std::generate_n(larger_array, 113, uniq);
    std::reverse_copy(std::begin(larger_array), std::end(larger_array), std::begin(smaller_array));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        std::cout << smaller_array[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `std::copy`, but with a sensible limit applied.

Comment: You should use `std::vector` instead of arrays. If you use arrays then you need to have a very specific reason for that, and that reason might influence the correct answer to your question. What do you REALLY want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you want the last `100` elements of `larger_array` copied in reverse order this should work. The only difference from your code is using `std::prev()` to get the first iterator.

```
std::reverse_copy(std::prev(std::end(larger_array), 100), std::end(larger_array), std::begin(smaller_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::copy`, something like:

```
std::copy(std::begin(largerArray), std::begin(largerArray) + 
    (std::end(smallerArray) - std::begin(smallerArray)),
    std::begin(smallerArray));
```

Comment: This gives me a segmentatioon fault.

Comment: @user4068376 Sorry, wrong way around.  Edited answer with correct solution.

Comment: @PaulEvans: I think you have your source and destination backwards.

Comment: This will copy from 0 to 100, when I want 14-113. In other words, it starts from the element that actually contains data up to the size of smaller array.